# Setting a tomcat property using spring boot application properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I want to set the maxSwallowSize property for boot supplied tomcat. 
My application.properties has this line:

```
server.context-parameters.maxSwallowSize=20971520
```

Doesn't work for some reason. Other properties like server.port work well.
Debugging the creation in TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory I see that there is a ServletContexInitializer (InitParameterConfiguringServletContextInitializer) with this property but it doesn't seem to be used in any way. (Even though it's in a variable name initializersToUse, ironic ;p)

I don't like the kill of a connection when the upload exceeds the max size set by

```
multipart.max-request-size=10MB
multipart.max-file-size=2MB
```

Is this the correct way of setting this property? During debuggin I can see that the IdentityInputFilter has the default value of 2MB.

newest version of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: Sorry, but the newest version of spring-boot-starter-web will be an old version the moment a newer version will be relased ;-) please state your exact version, that makes it easier for future readers. (which is e.g. me, since this question currently is two years old)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`server.context-parameters` (as [defined in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) can be used to specify the init parameters of the servlet context). `maxSwallowSize` is a property of the connector. That's a different thing I guess.

We don't have an explicit property for that but you can always configure it via your own `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`.

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
            super.customizeConnector(connector);
            if ((connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {
                (AbstractHttp11Protocol <?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(value);
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The configuration like above didn’t help me(I’m using Spring Boot 1.5.10)

I found that the solution was to set

**application.properties:**

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

and all uploads works OK without configurating Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

Configuration **spring.http.multipart.max-request-size** is not the same as **maxSwallowSize**. The former configures the application and the latter configures the Tomcat server.

So in *addition* to **spring.http.multipart** configuration you also should provide configuration for **maxSwallowSize**, which can simply be done for Spring Boot 2 by setting application property:

```
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=100MB
```