# Spring-boot controller error when url contains braces character

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a controller which receive requests as `GET` with 2 parameters `e` and `p`:

```
@GetMapping("")
public String getIframe(
    @RequestParam(value = "p", required = false) String p,
    @RequestParam(value = "e", required = false) String e
){
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
```

In some cases `e` and `p` values can contain `{}` characters.
It was working well in spring-boot 1, but after updating the module to spring-boot 2 it started to raise an exception:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 47: http://127.0.0.1:8080/shorteners/click/RikBV?e={CLICKID}&p={PUBID}
  at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
  at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
  at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3111)
  at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
  at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
  at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850)
  ... 45 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 47: http://127.0.0.1:8080/shorteners/click/RikBV?e={CLICKID}&p={PUBID}
  at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
  at fr.hamid.testApp.app.configurations.HeadersFilter.doFilter(HeadersFilter.java:43) [26 skipped]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [9 skipped]
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [2 skipped]
 [1 skipped]
```

Also, My filter class is as follow:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class HeadersFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String referer = request.getHeader("referer") ;
        if (referer != null && new UrlValidator().isValid(referer)) {
            URL url = new URL(referer);
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost());
        }
        else {
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-auth-token, x-requested-with, content-type, accept, " +
                "origin, referer, Authorization, customer-user-id, device-os, t-user-id, t-network-cache-capacity," +
                "t-network-bandwidth, device-client-date, dev-platform, sdk-version, sdk-type, app-package-name," +
                "device-imei, developer-key, device-model, device-os-version, secret-token, t-network-type");

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if (!"OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            //Exception raises here!
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

        response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "*");
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

When I use `wget` command it works well, but the exception raises when I call the url using browser!

Is there any way to handle these kind of urls?

Note: As customers are using these urls, I can not handle this problem by changing the `{}` characters with others. So, it is important to handle this server side!

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Would you please post some code?

Comment: Please post your controller code/

Comment: You cannot use PathVariable instead? Which will fix your issue?

Comment: @JaiDixit This is just a simple controller. However, I updated my question and added the method.

Comment: @VelNaga unfortunately this url pattern is in use by a huge amount of customers and I can not change it for now.

Comment: why dont you encode your query params and then get them back in controller ??

Comment: Ask them to encode the requestParameter alone(not entire URL) using URLEncoder.encode()

Comment: If the relaxedQueryChars approach doesn't work can you post the code for your filter fr.hamid.testApp.app.configurations.HeadersFilter as the error is coming out of there?

Comment: @pcoates, unfortunately, it didn't work. As it seems in the raised exception, the problem is related to spring-boot, not tomcat. Additionally, the required class has added to question :)

Comment: @hamidghasemi the HeadersFilter class doesn't seem to tie up with the stack trace. According to the stack trace line 43 of HeadersFilter calls URI.create(value). What's on line 43? I suggest you start your app in debug mode and step through the code in the filter.

Comment: @pcoates According to the stack trace, the exception arises in `doFilter()` method, and I assumed this is obvious. However, I added a comment to the code.

Comment: It's obvious it's in the doFilter method of HeadersFilter, but the next entry on the stack is URI.create(), not chain.doFilter(). So the stack trace doesn't seem to match the code you posted. Put a breakpoint there, run in debug and step through the code to find what's calling URI.create().

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `spring boot 2.2.0` it is possible to configure Tomcat so, that special characters are allowed in URLs.

Just sum the ones you wanna allow in the `application.properties`

In your case that is

```
server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars= {,}
```

all configurable chars are **`**, **{**, **}**, **[**, **]**, **^**, **<**, **>** and **|**

In `application.yml` that would be

```
server:
  tomcat:
    relaxed-query-chars: ['{','}']
```

Answer (score 2):

The url with {} in the query string is being rejected by tomcat as they are not valid url characters.

wget works because it urlencodes the querystring before sending it over {=%7B, }=%7D. The @RequestParam annotation results in a urldecoding, so you just see { and } in your variables. If you looked at the actual querystring you'd see %7B and %7D.

You can configure tomcat to be more relaxed about what characters it accepts, although it's best to get the clients to urlencode if you can.

[Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html) look for relaxedQueryChars, that's the option that allows you to tell tomcat to accept {} in the query string.

There are a few answers already about how to set this property, e.g. [Setting a tomcat property using spring boot application properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250030/setting-a-tomcat-property-using-spring-boot-application-properties)

```
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatConnectorCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TomcatWebServerCustomizer
        implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Connector connector) {
                connector.setAttribute("relaxedQueryChars", "{}");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the braces to show up in your params string.
You will have to use HTML URL Encoding in the URL used in the browser,
refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

So your URL in the browser will look something like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/shorteners/click/RikBV?e=%7BCLICKID%7D&p=%7BPUBID%7D

Using code below to test and print:

```
@GetMapping("/urlParamTest")
public void getIframe(@RequestParam(value = "p", required = false) String p,
        @RequestParam(value = "e", required = false) String e) {
    System.out.println("Hi " + p + " , " + e);
}
```

---

Console output:

```
Hi {PUBID} , {CLICKID}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems that you didn't read the Note and comments on question!

Comment: I was probably typing it out when they posted. Anyways its works.

Comment: @Code_Is_Law Thank you for the answer. But the main problem here is that I CAN NOT ask all customers to change the URL right now. I should find a way to handle braces for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could not solve the problem in spring boot and I had two choices:

1- Downgrade Spring-boot to the last version.

2- Add `if` statement in Nginx and encode the request parameters.

Although the second solution is not efficient and it probably slows down the serving requests, I choose that based on two reasons :

First of all, it was important for me to have Grafana to monitor my services and It was not possible with the old spring boot version.

Secondly, impacts on response time were negligible and I think it worth it.