# How to read query parameter with ^ in the URL

Tags: spring

I'm trying to implement a callback endpoint for eBay. This endpoint is called by eBay to hand the application a user token.

I can define my endpoint as expected

> http://localhost:8080/api/ebay/auth

Nothing unusual here. My enpoint looks like this, really basic:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = ["/api/ebay/auth"])
class EbayAuthController {

    @GetMapping(path = [""])
    fun getAccessToken(@RequestParam code: String) {
        println("Auth code: $code")
    }

}
```

Now eBay passes the parameter `code` with the value

> ?code=v^1.1%23i^1%23r^1%23p^3%23I^3%23f^0%23t^[excluded_user_token]&expires_in=299

When I call my endpoint with this data set, it returns `400 Bad Request`. I can reproduce this by adding `^` to any request. I read it's an unsafe character to use - but the issue is: Ebay uses this character to return the user token, so I must read it.

When I pass a sample with `http://localhost:8080/api/ebay/auth?code=123` it prints the code as expected.

I've never encountered that problem, can anyone help me or point me in the right direction how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried percent encoding? `v%5E1.1`

Comment: How can I tell Spring convert it into percent? I have no control over the data being send to the endpoint.

Comment: Spring only "sees" the decoded data. The request itself has to have the correct encoding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring-boot controller error when url contains braces character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611922/spring-boot-controller-error-when-url-contains-braces-character)

Comment: What I read here is that I have to setup a front-end endpoint that accepts the data sent by eBay, converts it and passes it to the endpoint? That seems excessive (on ebay's part)

Comment: Or maybe this does the trick https://stackoverflow.com/a/58440058/6500730

Comment: Yes, that was my last ink :)

Comment: If you post this as answer, I'd be happy to give you the correct answer badge.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58440058/112968) by [Dirk Deyne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9681755/dirk-deyne) to the question [Spring-boot controller error when url contains braces character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611922/spring-boot-controller-error-when-url-contains-braces-character), you can specify `server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars` in your `application.properties`:

```
server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars=^
```